# I run my espresso machine until my whole cup is full. What's my coffee called?

Tags: espresso, espresso-machine

I have a cheap espresso machine. I grind dark roast beans separately, fill a "double" filter with it, run the espresso machine and won't turn it off until my ~250ml cup is completely filled. I drink it right away, brewed coffee style, without adding anything.

It's not Americano (it's got crema all over it), too much water to be espresso, and to my understanding, Long Black is espresso added to water.

Is this simply, regular brewed coffee with crema?

Comment: I absolutely love this question. It feels very existential. Do we define espresso as that which comes out of an espresso machine? So call it whatever? I guess... and what's crema?

Comment: @EdCooper: It's the thin layer of foam at the top of a cup of espresso.

Comment: I call it, my next cuppacoffee.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'd say that it's a caffè crema which is generally made the way you make your coffee and is about 240 ml. It's about 3 times more water than a *normale*.

Comment: In Wikipedia it is said it is common in Belgium. However, I have never heard of that. It is very likely that I have spent my time at the north side of the country. Thanks for the info. 
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caffè_crema

Comment: Honestly, I've never actually been to Belgium; however, I'm really obsessed with crema so I make myself a caffè crema sometimes. I called it an _Eli_ stro because my name is Eli but then I found out it has an actual name.

Comment: It is also the "standard" coffee people drink in Germany.

Comment: @greenglass With the growing market share of bean-to-cup machines in offices and bakeries, it may seem that way (as they brew caffé crema), but I still think that classical filter coffee is more common.

Comment: People in Germany mainly drink Cappuccini when they go to cafés. There is a trend to black coffee, mainly in form of Americanos/Long Blacks but increasingly pour overs and other filter methods. I definitely think though that a Cappuccino is the most sold coffee in german cafés by quite a bit. The main exception are as mentioned before cafeterias at Unis and offices that have industrial grade been to cup machines. What comes out of those as cafe "creme" only takes like 10s to brew though...so not sure we should give it the name of an espresso based drink at all.

Answer (score 14):

I would also go for caffè crema (more water than a lungo). There is no strict agreement on at how much water does it stop being a lungo and starts being a crema. But I guess "lungo" is more well known around the world, at least on countries where Nespresso is available, since their capsules for long coffees are called "lungo".

Here in Mexico, the waiter / barista might ask you if you want your espresso "corto" (short) or "largo" (long). Corto is the usual espresso size (not ristretto) and largo is about twice the amount of water. This is not an uncommon practice, but not everyone offers it.

Anyhow, just be careful not to be over-extracting. If your coffee beans can handle that amount of water without over-extraction (which results in excessive bitterness because of burned-down oils, and possibly too much caffeine), great. Some beans do, some don't.

Have you tried a traditional americano (shot of espresso + added hot water)? Compare the flavor between both to get a reference on how a "normal" extraction goes on your beans vs. the extended extraction you are currently having.

Comment: I agree. Additionally, if you don't have a relatively coarse grind Caffè Crema will taste absolutely terrible.

Comment: So, a coarser grind will give a better Crema? Didn't know that. Will try it.

Answer (score 8):

This is called Lungo, Italian for "Long coffee". Typically it is prepared around 150 ml.

More info is here: 
[Lungo (Wikipedia).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lungo)

Answer (score 2):

A customer in the store that i work comes every day and buy this. He called it "super lugo". I think it's just a double lugo with extra water (from the grouphead). So you don't loose the taste of the espresso, if you want a kind of filter coffee with espresso taste.

Answer (score 2):

It can be called a caffè creme, a (very long) lungo, or a *spoiled cup of espresso*.

It is important to note that a lungo isn't achieved by just letting the water run for longer, you have to adjust the grind to get a faster flow, so that you get a larger volume in actually a shorter time.

If you grind for normal espresso and then let the machine run for a minute or two to fill your cup, your'e *over-extracting* your coffee which will result in an unpleasant taste.

The water should always be stopped at the "blonding point", when the stream gets lighter; do not let it run for long after that or you'll ruin your nice drink. Adjust the grind to get more or less water in the cup before that happens.

Answer (score 1):

In Italy this could be asked for by requesting a Caffè doppio (admittedly a bit borderline with a lungo)

Comment: Doesn't [doppio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppio) usually refer to a double-espresso, using twice the amount of grounds (and water) than a single/solo? Welcome to [coffee.se].

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. The op is actually filling a double filter and using it for 250ml cup. A friend of mine used to drink coffee like this (i'd say probably less than 250 but  huge in comparison to my espresso: for me it was a bit too extreme, that's why I noted it) and he explained to barmen like this. I don't know if a specific definition exist, this is admittedly only an anecdote. If it doesn't fit I can remove my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear; I meant that a "standard" doppio is double-grounds, double-water. This is that situation... *plus more water* put through the grounds. Your answer was short and I was just asking for a bit more clarification, which you gave; now it's more clear; thanks! Doppio wasn't mentioned elsewhere; feel free to leave it (or add to it). Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

This is a "Long" or a "Long Espresso".

In French Canada we call it an "Allongé".

But if you have a very big mug I would just call it blech!

Comment: Your answer is similar to [this one](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/a/2563/), but does include local information. Would you consider changing your answer to a comment?